# SqlAlchemy: handling table columns that have a dollar sign in their name

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

In SqlAlchemy you declare a variable for every table column. But I have to read from a table that has a column named `customer$partner$naziv` and you can't declare a variable with a name like that in Python. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Here is what I have (obviously not working):

```
class RfidSif(Base):
""""""
__tablename__ = 'rfid_sif'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
customer               = Column(Integer)
customer$partner$naziv = Column(String)
rfid_id                = Column(String)
rfid_name              = Column(String)
rfid_group_name        = Column(String)
rfid_comment           = Column(String)
rfid_startdate         = Column(Date)
rfid_enddate           = Column(Date)
activity               = Column(SmallInteger)
user_headless          = Column(Integer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, id, customer, customer$partner$naziv, rfid_id, rfid_name, rfid_group_name, rfid_comment, rfid_startdate, rfid_enddate, activity, user_headless):
    """"""
    self.id                     = id
    self.customer               = customer
    self.customer$partner$naziv = customer$partner$naziv
    self.rfid_id                = rfid_id
    self.rfid_name              = rfid_name
    self.rfid_group_name        = rfid_group_name
    self.rfid_comment           = rfid_comment
    self.rfid_startdate         = rfid_startdate
    self.rfid_enddate           = rfid_enddate
    self.activity               = activity
    self.user_headless          = user_headless

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __repr__(self):
    """"""
    return "<RfidSif - '%s': '%s' - '%s'>" % (self.id, self.rfid_id, self.name)
```

Comment: just fyi, aligning statements violates PEP8 (and is pretty ugly, especially if one of them is much longer than the others)

Comment: didn't know about PEP8 till now. But even though its ugly, I find it a lot more readable.

Comment: The problem is that you get extremely awful diffs when you add something that doesn't fit the current alignment. Instead of adding one line you add one line and change many more lines. That makes reviewing changes much worse. You also shouldn't add empty docstrings. Omit them and add them once you want to write something in them (but `__repr__` rarely needs one)

Comment: But if you change the alignment of all rows in the alignment, diff recognises this as one diff on multiple lines :) btw, would Elixir be more usefull for my case, since I'm only going to SELECT and INSERT and not really create new tables and databases?

Answer (score 3):

Simply specify the column name as the first argument and use a different attribute name:

```
customer_partner_naziv = Column('customer$partner$naziv', String)
```

Also, you do not need your own `__init__` - the default constructor accepts keyword arguments for everything (and you shouldn't set `id` manually anyway, it's usually a serial/autoincrement column)

Comment: Excelent! Thank you so much for the quick reply!